# How to compare dates and choose option from selection list?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write a code for the following (picture first to show the idea of form table):

[image]

I need to compare dates only when I choose 'Payment date' from dropdown list, this is my trigger. ManualDate can be chosen by user. If InvDate < ManualDate then we return InvDate and change to 'None' option on the selected list to be displayed (column 'Choice'). In 'ManualDate' we also show appriopriate date - in this case InvDate.

The issue is that I have to idea how to choose value from given cell and compare with other value from the other cell but in the same row.

My View:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="invoice">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="decisionList">
                    <option selected></option>
                    <option>Payment Date</option>
                    <option>None</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="dates" type="data">
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

My jQyery (just a poor try):

```
$('.decisionList').change(function () {


    const i = this.selectedIndex;
    var date =  $(this).closest('tr').find('.dates');


    if (i == 1 && ($('.invoice').val() < date.val())) { //if InvDate < ManualDate

        date.val($('.invoice').val()); //then we should return InvDate to our data input

    } else {
        date.val(); //if not  - return ManualDate
    }

    $(this).closest('tr').find('.decisionList')[2]; //make 'None' (index=2) as a selected option

});
```

I'm a beginner so please give me some hints. I really don't know how to compare values from corresponding cells in a given (not all) row. Maybe I need to use .each instruction and assign iterator value to each field (in every column) as to identify fields between columns?

Comment: Hi you need to update date value in first td ? what is `($('.invoice').val()` ?

Comment: @Swati I need to update value in 3rd td - class .dates. And by using ```($('.invoice').val()```  I want to get value from the cell (1st td - class .invoice). Is that correct way of geeting value from this cell? In fact the value is here: ```modelItem => item.InvDate```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing `change` event handler for select-box you can write event handler for `date` field. So, if the value of select-box is `1` then only `date` value will get change .

So , on change of `date` field we can get the closest tr using `$(this).closest()` and then using this we can get value of first `td` which has value for date field and select-box value as well .Then just compare both values and  change your `dates` input according to that.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.dates').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this).closest("tr");
  //get selectbox slected option index
  var i = $this.find("select option:selected").index()
  if (i == 1) {
    //get manual date
    var date_man = new Date($(this).val())
    //get inv date
    var data_inv = new Date($.trim($this.find("td:eq(0)").text()));
    //comapre
    if (data_inv < date_man) {
      $(this).val($.trim($this.find("td:eq(0)").text()));
    }
    //selcted index 2
    $this.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 2);
  } else {
    //empty
    $(this).val("")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="invoice">
      2020-09-18
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="decisionList">
        <option selected></option>
        <option>Payment Date</option>
        <option>None</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="dates" type="date">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="invoice">
      2020-10-31
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="decisionList">
        <option selected></option>
        <option>Payment Date</option>
        <option>None</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="dates" type="date">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```